# AJAX submit form and include PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Okay, so I know there's lot of bits about submitting forms/including PHP files using AJAX already, but I am an absolute newbie at JavaScript (within reason), so I've been forced to post a question.

Anyhow, I have form with a drop down menu. When the form is submitted, it creates a GET variable, which PHP then uses to include the relative file (it's up against a white-list so no values can be faked).

How would I go about getting JavaScript to submit the form and then load the correct PHP file after, without needing a refresh?

Here's the form and code:

Form:

```
                <div class="formC">
<form method="get" action="contents.php" id="myForm">
    <select name="TutorialBlock">
<option value="alltuts">Show All Tutorials</option>
<option value="tuts1">Block One - Starting</option>
<option value="tuts2">Block Two</option>
<option value="tuts3">Block Three</option>

</select>
    <input type="submit" value="Show Block" id="submitButtonId">
</form>
</div>
```

The PHP:

```
 <?php
$whitelist = array(
'tuts1',
'tuts2',
'tuts3',
'alltuts'
);

if(isset($_GET['TutorialBlock']) && !empty($_GET['TutorialBlock'])) {
    // now make sure it's in the whitelist.
    if(!in_array($_GET['TutorialBlock'], $whitelist)) {
        die('<p class="info">The file does not exist, or isn not on the whitelist. Please choose from the dropdown menu</p>');
    } else {
        include 'includes/'.$_GET['TutorialBlock'].'.php';
    }
} else {
     echo '<p class="info">Choose your tutorial block using the drop down menu above</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: If you don't want to refresh, you need to use AJAX instead of submitting a form. Read a tutorial on AJAX, expecting us to write all the code for you is a bit much.

Comment: It's mainly about how I'd connect both parts. I know roughly how to both submit the form and include the data, just not at the same time

Comment: You make the AJAX call, and use `$("#tutorialDiv").html(response)` to insert the response into the page.

Comment: That's quite helpful actually, thank you